# Merge Mail Directory

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, mail-merge

I am using Word 2010 and trying to implement into a cover letter a listing with all the recipients of the letter. I am using the Mail Merge (Mailings > Start Mail merge > Directories). The problem is, that if I try to write my letter or whatever, it repeats it after each recipient.

The only thing I want is to insert my directory list with all the recipients (with their e-mail, phone etc) into my document.

Comment: Mail merge is the wrong tool. Use copy and paste.